# Not printing output ? python

Tags: python

```
def binary_search(li, targetValue):
   low, high = 0, len(li)
   while low <= high:
        mid = (high - low)/2 + high
        if li[mid] > targetValue:
             low = mid - 1;
        elif li[mid] < targetValue:
             high = mid + 1;
        elif li[mid] == targetValue:
             return "we found it!"
   print start, end 
   return False
```

I almost positive it  works. It works when the `targetValue` is present in the array, but when you ask it to find a value outside of the given elements, it doesn't work any more ...

Does anyone know why?

Comment: This line confuses me: `mid = (high - low)/2 + high`. Why would the 'middle' be high minus low divided by 2 (which sounds pretty 'middlish') added to the highpoint (which sounds larger than 'high'). What am I missing here?

Comment: This line confuses me: `print start, end`

Comment: ^I guess I didn't get that far.

Comment: This whole thing confuses me...

Comment: Have you tried putting in `print` statements and following what's happening? This is the 3rd question based on the same code within an hour which leaves some doubt about efforts to solve this yourself first :p

Comment: also `if li[mid] > targetValue:` then shouldn't it be `low = mid + 1`  also `high = mid -1` for the next condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to print, but I see where there might be some misbehavior from that function. Try something like this instead:

```
# binary search for list with desending values
def binary_search(li, targetValue):
    low, high = 0, len(li) - 1  # min & max index
    while low <= high:          # loop til high & low switch
        mid = (high + low) / 2  # midpoint (rounds down)
        if li[mid] > targetValue: low = mid + 1     # confine to upper half
        elif li[mid] < targetValue: high = mid - 1  # confine to lower half
        elif li[mid] == targetValue: return mid     # found it!
    return None  # nothing to return (low/high switched, so it wasn't found)
```

This will return the index of the match if `targetValue` is in `li`, or `None` otherwise. Use like:

```
li = [10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1]

if binary_search(li, 500) is None: print '500 not found!'
else: print '500 found!'

i = binary_search(li, 10)
if i is None: print '10 not found!'
else: print 'Found 10 at index ' + str(i) + '!'
```

That would output:

```
500 not found!
Found 10 at index 3!
```

For an acceding `li`, just switch `<` and `>`:

```
def binary_search(li, targetValue):
    low, high = 0, len(li) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) / 2
        if li[mid] < targetValue: low = mid + 1
        elif li[mid] > targetValue: high = mid - 1
        elif li[mid] == targetValue: return mid
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

```
import bisect
bisect.bisect_left(li, targetValue)
```